# performance: why is (float of sum of map int of integer chars) twice as slow as (sum of map float of integer chars)?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I want to understand why the first example took twice as long than the second one. My intuition says that converting integer chars to `int` should be atleast as fast as converting them to `float`, if not faster.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("float(sum(map(int,['5', '8', '3', '6', '3', '9', '5', '0', '1', '0'])))")
6.165183067321777

>>> timeit("sum(map(float, ['5', '8', '3', '6', '3', '9', '5', '0', '1', '0']))")
2.928786039352417
```

**edit**: duplicate of [Why is float() faster than int()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232733/why-is-float-faster-than-int)

even the presence of extra `float` call in the first example is not the cause because I ran timeit for it as well and it takes 1% time as compared to these operations (for same number)

```
>>> from timeit import timeit 
>>> timeit("float(sum(map(int,['5', '8', '3', '6', '3', '9', '5', '0', '1', '0']
)))", number=100000)
0.6287150382995605
>>> timeit("sum(map(float, ['5', '8', '3', '6', '3', '9', '5', '0', '1', '0']))"
,number=100000)
0.2976219654083252
>>> timeit("float(1)",number=100000)
0.02610301971435547
```

I tried `dis`, but nothing there helped me either:

```
def a(li):
  return float(sum(map(int,li)))

def b(li):
  return sum(map(float, li))

# >>> dis(a)
#   4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (float)
#               3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (sum)
#               6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (map)
#               9 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (int)
#              12 LOAD_FAST                0 (li)
#              15 CALL_FUNCTION            2
#              18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              24 RETURN_VALUE        

# >>> dis(b)
# 4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
#             3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (map)
#             6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (float)
#             9 LOAD_FAST                0 (li)
#            12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
#            15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#            18 RETURN_VALUE
```

I was using python 2.7.12 for this test

Comment: Because function calling in Python is expensive as hell? Most likely things would change with bigger input.

Comment: This can be simplified to just why `map(float, [...])` is faster than `map(int, [...])`. I'm seeing `int` taking 2.9x the time than `float`.

Comment: @PauloScardine then why did `timeit("float(1)",number=100000)` ran so much fast? do you think python was caching result there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232733/why-is-float-faster-than-int

Comment: I'm closing this question^

Comment: I reopened the question because [_Why is float() faster than int()?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232733/why-is-float-faster-than-int) was never resolved satisfactorily in my opinion (or the OP of that question).

Comment: @martineau all due respect (and I mean that, I love your work here) should we really allow dupes for every question not answered to our delight? I would prefer someone answering the other question, because it is clearly superior (or at least more to the point).

Comment: @Paulo: Thanks...I try to do my best. Regarding this question: I agree that the other question is more direct, but its one answer is unsatisfactory and inconclusive—plus, since it's so old, I doubt it'll see much action at this point. Maybe this one will. I also think you might be right about an extra function call possibly being the cause.