# Why my code cannot find maximum number in string of numbers (space separated)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I gave this string to my python code from which I wanted to find the maximum.

```
>>> a = ("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
>>> a = a.split(" ")
>>> max(a)
>>> 6
```

Can someone please explain me why it is not returning 542?
At last, I found the correct code:

```
>>> a = a.split(" ");
>>> a = [int(i) for i in a];
>>> return str(max(a))
```

But could someone please teel me my foolishness in the former code.

Comment: After the split, `a` will still be a list of strings. Map it to a list of ints before calling `max`

Comment: Try printing out the value of `a` after the split line and you'll see

Comment: **incorrect** copy paste in your question. `>>> max(a)` in the REPL will output `'6'`, not `>>> 6`! And that should serve as a hint :)

Comment: Yes I didnt observed that

Answer (score 2):

You can also find the maximum string as if interpreted as an integer by passing a `key`

```
max(a.split(), key=int)

'542'
```

And make it an int afterwards

```
int(max(a.split(), key=int))

542
```

Comment: That's nice. Do you know why it is faster to use `key=float`? `%timeit max(a.split(), key=int)` gives `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.68 µs per loop` and `%timeit max(a.split(), key=float)` gives `100000 loops, best of 3: 2.43 µs per loop`.

Comment: I don't know.  Interesting though.

Comment: Seems to hold also for much larger lists.

Comment: Python 3.6, can't see much difference really. 3.77 vs 3.67... that one looks strange

Comment: Seems to be a base ambiguity issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232733/why-is-float-faster-than-int

Answer (score 1):

```
max([int(x) for x in a.split()])
```

This will convert `a` into a list of ints and find the correct max. Strings are compared char by char, comparing charcodes.

```
max(int(x) for x in a.split())
```

The above works too, without creating a list, as a generator variant.

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension with `[` and `]`. `max` can directly take a generator expression

Comment: Alternatively, `max(map(int, a))` works for Python 3.x & 2.7, and is lazy in 3.x.

Comment: @sshashank124 Thanks for the comment, I edited my answer

Comment: `max` does not do double generation. could you please provide a source on that?

Comment: @sshashank124 Apparently I can't find any. I had in mind a similar case where I read that generators indeed double up the number of generations. There was a popular StackOverflow entry about that. However this might have been a similar case. In the meantime I will definitely amend this answer.

Comment: I'm not claiming that it definitely doesn't but I tried searching it and skimming the src code and I couldn't find it. I think it would be safer to keep it out of the discussion in the answer itself haha.

Comment: @sshashank124 the gen expr is very slightly slower. `test_list = list(np.random.randint(0, 500, 100000).astype(str))`. From `timeit` - list: `29.7 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`, gen expr: `32.7 ms ± 593 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: @Cleb added a.split(). roganjosh thanks for the benchmark (anyway OP already wrote `a= a.split()` but it is ok to specify)

Answer (score 0):

```
max(map(int, a.split(" ")))
# 542
```